# What does ".endr" exactly mean in this context? Is it a padding or an end of something marker?

Tags: types, x86

```
ldt:
    .rept 4
    .quad 0
    .endr
ldt_bottom:
```

What does .endr mean? What does it do in terms of affecting the format of the data in memory?

Comment: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/Rept.html#Rept

Answer (score 0):

.endr marks the end of the section that .rept marks the beginning of.

.rept doesn't just repeat the following line, it repeats all the lines until the .endr statement.

In your example, .quad 0 gets repeated 4 times.